# Error on strtotime()

Tags: php, datetime

```
$dateTime="2011-10-12 00:00:00";

echo $newDateTime =date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($dateTime.' -1 hours 30 minutes'));
```

The result of above code is **'2011-10-11 23:30:00'**. However, the correct answer should be
2011-10-11 22:30:00.

Is there anying wrong in the code and can anyone help me?

Many thanks

Comment: You're initialising $dateTime but then using $dateTime2 in your strtotime expression.

Comment: @liquorvicar, it was typo mistake

Answer (score 2):

`23:30` is the expected result (once you know what is happening).

The relative parts of the string (`-1 hours 30 minutes`) are processed **separately** as `-1 hours` and `30 minutes`. They are two instances of the `number space? (unit | 'week')` format as described in the [*Relative Formats*](http://php.net/datetime.formats.relative) documentation.

Because of this the cumulative relative change in the time is only `-30 minutes`, which from midnight gives `23:30`.

To get the effect that you desire, either:

- use a single relative statement (e.g. `-90 minutes`)
- make your original minutes statement negative as `-1 hours -30 minutes`
- or, use the special `ago` format as `1 hours 30 minutes ago`

See http://php.net/datetime.formats.relative for more details.

Comment: Interesting, I'd never realised that

Answer (score 1):

date functions aren't fully daylight savings aware. Try using dateTime objects instead

Comment: Daylight savings is not the issue in this particular case.